# Getting error when trying to create jupyter notebook file in VScode

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have used jupyter notebook, for a while now. And have never had any problems.

I am now trying to create a **.ipynb** file in VScode, but I keep getting this error. I also get this error, when trying to open old **.ipynb** files.

**Any ideas?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By2O0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question.

I fixed the issue by upgrading my python to version 3.12 and then uninstalling and reinstalling VScode.

Fixed the issue